# Jdom namespace properly recognized, but attributes not parsing

Tags: java, attributes, xml-namespaces, jdom

I'm extracting individual elements from an RSS feed using jdom and had no problems doing so, except when it came to getting the URL out of the "href" attribute of the "link" element from my "atom" namespace.

Here is the XML snippet I'm testing on :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

<channel>
   <title>Title Test</title>
   <atom:link type="application/rss+xml" rel="self" href="https://www.testingRSS.com/site/infos/rss/news.php"/>
   <link>https://www.testingRSS.com/</link>
   <description>The News</description>
   <language>fr-ca</language>
   <managingEditor>webmaster@testingRSS.com</managingEditor>
   <webMaster>webmaster@testingRSS.com</webMaster>
```

I'm trying to parse "https://www.testingRSS.com/site/infos/rss/news.php" out of this, and display it in a jfield.

Here is the code I'm currently running and fiddling with :

```
    Namespace atom = rootElement.getNamespace("atom");
    System.out.println(atom);
    //the above outputs [Namespace: prefix "atom" is mapped to URI "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"] which is correct
    
    Element link = new Element("link", atom);
    feedLink = link.getAttributeValue("href", atom);
    
    System.out.println("Link : " + feedLink);
    //outputs Null.
```

So I'm getting the correct Namespace out of my jdom document using the root element and the test output is giving me the URI it is mapped to so I know it is correctly defined.

Every other field in the Channel parsed without issue, and I simply cannot get this URL to parse, and even

```
    link.getAttributesSize()
```

returns 0.

I tried specifically declaring "href" as an attribute of element "link" in namespace "atom" and getValue() out of it but always comes back Null.

Comment: Have you considered using an ATOM specific library to parse the file? It could handle it better.

Comment: Do _"type"_ and _"rel"_ return values?  Is it just _"href"_?

Answer (score 0):

Attributes typically don't have any namespace, so you should just access it with:

```
link.getAttributeValue("href");
```